# Dell R620 - problems with boot order

Tags: boot, dell-poweredge

I have an "old" Dell R620 that in a previous life was used as a EXI host.  The machine has a 1G SD card with which had the VMware software on it.  I have now installed linux on the HD.

The problem is that The boot order just has HD C: for disks i.e. no separate entries for the SD card and HD.  It always tries to boot from the SD, even when there is nothing there to boot from.  Deleting partitions from the SD caused the boot to abort with no error message early in the sequence.

How can I force it to boot from the hard disk?

Comment: What's the boot order set in iDRAC? This model went EoSL over five years ago, why are you still using it?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you've asked this question twice. I posted an answer to your original question here https://serverfault.com/a/1127699/355588